# My prefix is a lie

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

Another 'Riley riddle':

> My prefix is a lie,
> My infix is what some people pledge to,
> My suffix is to have less.

**What is the word?**

Comment: Can anyone make a riley riddle tag?

Comment: Such a tag has already been created several times... and then removed. "Riddle" and "word" are apparently enough.

Comment: @Duck I originally suggested the idea in [meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/do-prefix-suffix-infix-riddles-deserve-their-own-tag). But the community decided against the creation of this tag for the same reason mentioned by xhienne.

Comment: Oh, ok. But so many people make them it should be more clarified.

Comment: Ah, a riley tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My very quick and unprocessed guess

> Conflagration

My prefix is a lie,

> 'con' man

My infix is what some people pledge to,

> I pledge allegiance to the 'Flag' of _____.

My suffix is to have less

> You're left with less food, if you have to 'ration' it.